# AdminLTE - How to collapse sidebar but not top navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

AdminLTE 2.4.3 Demo: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

I'd like to collapse the left side bar but not the top nav bar when clicking the collapse icon.

I've played around with it but can't seem to find an easy solution for this. Because the collapse function is applied on the `<body>` tag, I'm not sure how to get around it.

For instance, I'd like it to collapse like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these styles

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .logo {
    width: 230px;
    z-index: 1001;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .logo>.logo-mini {
       display: none;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .logo>.logo-lg {
       display: block;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this but the top nav still collapses? Also, it looks like there are extra braces in the code :)

Comment: Sorry i missed some braces, Try the updated answer :)